# Using more than 1 values in a for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I need help to use a 'for loop' with more than 2 values which are going together. This is my code:

```
for( x=1 , y=1 ; x<6 , y<10 ; x++  , y++){
    cout << "x:" << x << endl;
    cout << "y:" << y << endl;
```

Right now when I run it ... x and y are going up to 9 
although I want them to run together but i want x to stop outputting at 6 and i want y to continue to 9..but I don't know how to do it or is it even possible to do so.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean, other than using an `if` condition to check the value of `x` before printing it out?

Comment: @Pavlin Edrev  What are you going to do in the body of the loop when x is equal to 6 and y is less than 10?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I just want to change their values..by showing each changed number...if this gives meaning to you

Comment: @PavlinEdrev It does not give me meaning because the variable y has more values than the variable x. So show what output you are expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use `c++` so someone correct me if my syntax is wrong, but as a broad-spectrum programmer I'd imagine the solution would look something like this:

```
for (x=1, y=1; x<6 || y<10;) {
    if (x<6) {
        cout << "x:" << x << endl;
        ++x;
    }
    if (y<10) {
        cout << "y:" << y << endl;
        ++y;
    }
}
```

There are also ways to achieve this affect without leaving the core of your for loop using ternary operators but for the sake of simplicity I've excluded that here.

Comment: shouldn't the conditional be `x<6 || y<10`? as it stands, this will stop at 6

Comment: The while-conditional should be `y < 10` and the `if (y < 10)` is obselete.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x no clue why I put an `&&` must have been half awake

Comment: Thanks for the answer ,but the problem in this code is that x still goes up to 9, it is just not showing...My ask was to stop x at 6 and continue y to 9

Comment: @PavlinEdrev my apologies I actually had that logic originally, somebody edited my post removing that part. I've edited it back in.

Comment: @user2176127 Note^ guess it was needed o.o

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Well that actually helped me just the way I wanted! Thank you :)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw: With the increments before the output statements your code would not output 1, ever. Fixed that for you. It's generally a good idea to (1) test your code before posting, unless it's trivial, and (2) ignore the voters on SO.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf thanks you're right! And I don't have a C++ IDE so I couldn't test

Comment: There are a number of [online C++ compilers](https://isocpp.org/get-started), including [Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/) (created by an SO reader).

Answer (score 0):

test.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    for(int i = 1; i < 6; ++i) {
        std::cout << "x: " << i << std::endl;
        std::cout << "y: " << i << std::endl;
    }
    for(int i = 6; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << "y: " << i << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
x: 1
y: 1
x: 2
y: 2
x: 3
y: 3
x: 4
y: 4
x: 5
y: 5
y: 6
y: 7
y: 8
y: 9
```

Comment: I guess each iteration of the loop generally takes less time if it checks for 1 instead of 2 conditions. But I am not sure how would the compiler optimize the code. May be this doesn't matter after all.

Comment: That did help me ! Thanks a lot :)   (I am a beginner so I don't really care about optimizing the code yet.

Answer (score -6):

The simplest, for a natural interpretation of the question, is a nested loop:

```
for( int y = 1; y < 10; ++y )
{
    for( int x = 1; x < 6; ++x )
    {
        cout << "x:" << x << endl;
        cout << "y:" << y << endl;
    }
}
```

If instead you actually want two values called `x` and `y` that are always the same, and you want to do one thing for `x < 6` and something else for `y < 10`, then a single loop counter suffices:

```
for( int i = 1; i < 10; ++i )
{
    int const y = i;
    if( i < 6 )
    {
        int const x = i;
        // Do the x and y thing here. E.g.
        cout << "x: " << x << endl;
    }
    // Do the y only thing here. E.g.
    cout << "y: " << y << endl;
}
```

If you meant something else then you need to **clarify** your question, e.g. with an example of desired output.